# change mySQL subquery to a join for efficiency

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is it possible to change the following mySQL query to use a join instead of a subquery for efficiency (or another way to increase efficiency)?  I have a table with patient visits to an emergency department.  The table lists arrival and departure time.  I need the query to return the total number of patients that were already present in the emergency department (the "census") when the patient arrived.

My table looks something like this:

```
+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | name |       arrival       |      departure      |
+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | Joe  | 2010-01-01 00:00:00 | 2010-01-01 02:00:00 |
|    2 | John | 2010-01-01 00:05:00 | 2010-01-01 03:00:00 |
|    3 | Jane | 2010-01-01 01:00:00 | 2010-01-01 04:00:00 |
...
```

With a desired result like this:

```
+------+--------+
| name | census |
+------+--------+
| Joe  |   0    |
| John |   1    |
| Jane |   2    |
...
```

The following query works, but is quite slow (about 3.5 seconds on 180,000 rows).  Is there a way to increase the efficiency of this query (with some sort of join, or other method)?

```
select name, arrival,
    (SELECT count(*)
FROM patient_arrivals as b
WHERE b.arrival <= a.arrival and b.departure >= a.departure) as census
FROM patient_arrivals as a
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `join` will help.  Instead, you need to restructure the query.  The following gets the number of patients in the room at any particular time:

```
  select t, sum(num) as num, @total := @total + num as total
  from (select arrival as t, 1 as num
        from patient_arrivals
        union all
        select departure, -1
        from patient_arrivals
       ) t cross join
       (select @total := 0) vars
  group by t
  order by t
```

Then, you can use this as a subquery for the join:

```
select pa.*, t.total as census
from patient_arrivals pa join
     (select t, sum(num) as num, @total := @total + num as total
      from (select arrival as t, 1 as num
            from patient_arrivals
            union all
            select departure, -1
            from patient_arrivals
           ) t cross join
           (select @total := 0) vars
      group by t
      order by t
     ) tnum
     on pa.arrival = tnum.t;
```

This gives the number when the patient arrives.  For the total that overlap:

```
select pa.*, max(t.total) as census
from patient_arrivals pa join
     (select t, sum(num) as num, @total := @total + num as total
      from (select arrival as t, 1 as num
            from patient_arrivals
            union all
            select departure, -1
            from patient_arrivals
           ) t cross join
           (select @total := 0) vars
      group by t
      order by t
     ) tnum
     on tnum.t between pa.arrival and pa.departure
group by pa.id
```